# Entity Framework Core Explicit Loading how to ignore deeper nested entities

Tags: nested, entity-framework-core

I have a database with the following tables:

User:

```
    public class User
    {
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Department DefaultDepartment { get; set; }       
        public ICollection<RoleDepartment> RoleDepartment{ get; set; }
    }
```

Role:

```
  public class Role
  {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string Permissions { get; set; }
      public ICollection<RoleDepartment> RoleDepartment{ get; set; }

  }
```

RoleDepartment:

```
   public class RoleDepartment
   {
       public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
       public string UserId { get; set; }
       public int RoleId { get; set; }

       public Department Department { get; set; }
       public User User { get; set; }
       public Role Role { get; set; }
   }
```

Department

```
   public class Department
   {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public ICollection<RoleDepartment> RoleDepartment { get; set; }
   }
```

when i get user data as follow

```
   User user = dbContext.Users
       .Single(u => u.UserId == user_id);
   
   dbContext.Entry(user).Reference(u => u.DefaultDepartment).Load();
   dbContext.Entry(user).Collection(u => u.RoleDepartment).Load();
```

I receive too much data

```
{

  "UserId": "***",
  "Name": "***",
  "DefaultDepartment": {
    "Id": "**",
    "Name": "***",
    "RoleDepartment": [
      {
        "DepartmentId": "**",
        "UserId": "***",
        "RoleId": "**",
        "User": {
          "UserId": "***",
          "Name": "***",
          "RoleDepartment": [
            {
              "DepartmentId": "**",
              "UserId": "***",
              "RoleId": "**"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "RoleDepartment": [
    {
      "DepartmentId": "**",
      "UserId": "***",
      "RoleId": "**",
      "User": {
        "UserId": "***",
        "Name": "***",
        "DefaultDepartment": {
          "Id": "**",
          "Name": "***",
          "RoleDepartment": [
            {
              "DepartmentId": "**",
              "UserId": "***",
              "RoleId": "**"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "DepartmentId": "**",
      "UserId": "***",
      "RoleId": "**",
      "Department": {
        "Id": "**",
        "Name": "***",
        "RoleDepartment": []
      },
      "User": {
        "UserId": "***",
        "Name": "***",
        "DefaultDepartment": {
          "Id": "**",
          "Name": "***",
          "RoleDepartment": []
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I want something like this:

```
{

  "UserId": "***",
  "Name": "***",
  "DefaultDepartment": {
    "Id": "**",
    "Name": "***",
    "RoleDepartment": [
      {
        "DepartmentId": "**",
        "UserId": "***",
        "RoleId": "**"
      }
    ]
  },
  "RoleDepartment": [
    {
      "DepartmentId": "**",
      "UserId": "***",
      "RoleId": "**",
    
      
    },
    {
      "DepartmentId": "**",
      "UserId": "***",
      "RoleId": "**"
    }
  ]
}
```

There is a way to ignore the nested User and Department entities?

I want to ignore auto-loaded data when I use explicit-loading.

Did I miss something?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a self referencing loop. If you are not using [NewtonsoftJson](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson/) install it using,

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson
```

You can then edit your startup.cs where you add in Newtonsoft to configure the `ReferenceLoopHandling`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(x => x.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);
}
```

There is another way to avoid reference loops and that is to tell the serializer to not serialize a property at all. In *both* Newtonsoft.Json and System.Text.Json there is an attribute called JsonIgnore,

```
   public class RoleDepartment
   {
       public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
       public string UserId { get; set; }
       public int RoleId { get; set; }

       public Department Department { get; set; }
       [JsonIgnore]
       public User User { get; set; }
       public Role Role { get; set; }
   }
```

But the recomended way is to create DTOs/ViewModels and map your Entities with them. Refer [this](https://code-maze.com/automapper-net-core/) for more info.

***Edit***:
You can stop reference loops for this case only as follows.

```
User user = dbContext.Users
   .Single(u => u.UserId == user_id);
   
dbContext.Entry(user).Reference(u => u.DefaultDepartment).Load();
dbContext.Entry(user).Collection(u => u.RoleDepartment).Load();

var Settings = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
};
var TheJSON = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user, user.GetType().BaseType, Settings);
```

Also you can create an anonymous object as follows and return it as well.

```
dbContext.Users.Select(x => new { Prop1 = x.Property1, Prop2 = x.Property2 });
```

Comment: I am already using NewtonsoftJson and I want to exclude the properties only in this case

Comment: I am already using NewtonsoftJson with ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore

Comment: Then I think you need to cretae DTOs to project only what you want to return, else you can return anonymous object. `myDbContext.MyObjects.Select(x => new { Prop1 = x.Property1, Prop2 = x.Property2 });`

Comment: Thanks @NishānWickramarathna for the help, the solution for me was: 
`var user = dbContext.Users.Select(x => new User{UserId = x.UserId, DefaultDepartment = x.DefaultDepartment, RoleDepartment = x.RoleDepartment .Select(s => new RoleDepartment {DepartmentId = s.DepartmentId, UserId = s.UserId, RoleId = s.RoleId }).ToList()}).Single(u => u.UserId == user_id);
`